# How to add property to a model through database context?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, .net-standard

**strong text**I have an auto generated field inside Database table but this field is not added into model. This model is being shared among .net standard and framework projects. However, in .net framework I need to add this field into model to insert or update. If not I will get **DbUpdateConcurrencyException**. In core version, there is no issue and it can work without putting the field, on the other hand, having the field that side gives a problem when update.

The field is an identity field and attribute is set up as follow **[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]**

If it is **DatabaseGeneratedOption.computed** or removed following exception triggers
**DbUpdateConcurrencyException**

If it is mapped to **DatabaseGeneratedOption.None** following error occurs
**Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Inspection' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF**

Could anyone tell me how to add a field programatically in database context so that I could remove the property from the model or may be any work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

If you are schema first approach, you can do following steps:

1.Try Create a Non-Identity primary key column on a table.

2.Remove the Entity model from EDMX.

3.Go back and set the PK identity to true.

4.Update EDMX by adding the entity.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed model attribute to DatabaseGeneratedOption.computed for that property and .Net Framework side I override that attribute with Identity in DatabaseContext